# Create dataframe with (for each cell) averages of other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of about 20 dataframes, all with the same structure (same rows and columns).
I want to create a new df, where each cell is equal to the average of the corresponding (same row/column) cells of the listed dfs.

So, for example, if we have just 2 dfs (A and B), I need the following:

```
A=
   A  B  C  D
0  7  6  8  7
1  7  0  7  6
2  9  2  7  0

B=
   A  B  C  D
0  6  9  2  7
1  4  4  5  7
2  6  8  5  4

Average=
     A    B    C    D
0  6.5  7.5  5.0  7.0
1  5.5  2.0  6.0  6.5
2  7.5  5.0  6.0  2.0
```

I tried this code, but it's pretty slow (the real dfs are quite large) and messes up the order of columns:

```
dfs = [A,B]

Average = pd.concat([each.stack() for each in dfs],axis=1)\
             .apply(lambda x:x.mean(),axis=1)\
             .unstack()
```

Is there a better alternative? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -

```
(A+B) / 2
```

**Output**

```
     A    B    C    D
0  6.5  7.5  5.0  7.0
1  5.5  2.0  6.0  6.5
2  7.5  5.0  6.0  2.0
```

For scaling up to more `dfs`, put all of them in a list and just use `sum(list)`. Edit: Based on @younggoti's reco-

```
list_of_df = [A,B]
sum(list_of_df)/len(list_of_df)
```

Comment: Wow, great. To make it more general, I tried  ` averages = sum(dfs)/len(dfs) `, and seems to work fine.